# LevelDB database client

Tags: gratis, database-browser

[LevelDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB) is an open-source on-disk key-value store written by Google and used in Google Chrome. It's faster than SQLite, but its files can get corrupted more easily.

A sample file can be found at `~/.config/chromium/Default/Local Extension Settings/pafkbggdmjlpgkdkcbjmhmfcdpncadgh/000459.ldb` or similar.

How to have a look at the content of such files, without having to write a program?
A browser would be great, but just dumping all data is already enough.

There is no official client, just official client libraries.

Comment: Try doing a Web search for [ [`LevelDB GUI`](https://www.google.com/search?q=LevelDB+GUI) ]. You'll see that there are multiple options out there.

Comment: @unforgettableid: Indeed a few have appeared since 2014 it seems. Could you please write an answer about your favorite one? I will most certainly accept your answer. Thanks a lot for the investigation!

Comment: I've only ever so far struggled with FastoNoSQL, and haven't gotten it fully working yet, so don't yet know which is best :)

Comment: @unforgettableid: FastoNoSQL is intended to be compatible with many database formats, which unfortunately makes the interface very counter-intuitive. I am sure any LevelDB-specific tool is better.

Comment: @unforgettableid if you think that something not working in FastoNoSQL please create but here: https://github.com/fastogt/fastonosql/issues .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [python](http://www.python.org) or [iPython](http://ipython.org/) with the [LevelDb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/leveldb) library to do the sort of thing you are looking for including quickly generating dumps, queries, etc.

Example:

```
>>> import leveldb
>>> db = leveldb.LevelDB('./db')
>>> print db.Get('hello')
world

>>> print list(db.RangeIter(key_from = '2', key_to = '5'))
[('2', 'string_2'), ('3', 'string_3'), ('4', 'string_4'), ('5', 'string_5')]
```

More documentation can be found on the [web site](https://code.google.com/p/py-leveldb/).

### Update 2022

It seems that levelbd may now be unsupported but with the newer Plyvel library *and f-strings* getting a dump can be even simpler:

```
import plyvel
db = plyvel.DB('/tmp/testdb/', create_if_missing=False) # Open making sure it exists
for key, value in db:
    print(f"{key} : {value}") # Not to dump to a file add file="some_name.txt" to print)
```

The documentation for Pluvel is [here](https://plyvel.readthedocs.io/).

*Thanks to @gromain for pointing this out!*

Comment: Plyvel is now a better alternative, as leveldb was abandoned:
https://pypi.org/project/plyvel/

Comment: @gromain - thanks for letting me know - answer updated to reflect.

Answer (score 7):

[FastoNoSQL](http://fastonosql.com) is an open source ([GitHub](https://github.com/fastogt/fastonosql)) and free GUI client that supports LevelDB databases.

[image: LevelDB screenshot]

Comment: I tried the 64-bit version. It appears to crash silently on entry-level (Pentium and Celeron) 64-bit CPUs. I filed bug reports [here](https://github.com/fastogt/fastonosql/issues/29) and [here](https://github.com/fastogt/fastonosql/issues/28). Until the problem is fixed, Pentium and Celeron users may have to use the 32-bit version instead. The 32-bit version uses simpler instructions and therefore works fine even on low-end 64-bit CPUs.

Comment: Trying to open a local .ldb file in FastoNoSQL is a bit confusing. I have to create a new database connection. I'm giving up for now; maybe I'll try again some more tomorrow.

Comment: It's not free anymore...